# ng-flow upload programmatically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-flow

I am currently using ng-flow to perform a file upload. It appears that the default action of selecting a file is to upload immediately. I'd like to override this so that files are selected and only uploaded on button click. Perhaps I am misreading the documentation, but thus far I have the following:

```
<div flow-init="{target: '/upload'}"
     flow-files-submitted="$flow.upload()"
     flow-file-success="$file.msg = $message">

  <input type="file" flow-btn/>
  Input OR Other element as upload button
  <span class="btn" flow-btn>Upload File</span>

  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="file in $flow.files">
        <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
        <td>{{file.name}}</td>
        <td>{{file.msg}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

This appears to work and I can see the network request going out. I located [flow.js upload file on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25740110/flow-js-upload-file-on-click) and attempted to follow the suggested answer, however `$flow` was undefined in the respective function.

So, how does one programmatically upload files using ng-flow?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At first, `flow-files-submitted` event is triggered when user pick a file (misleading name). So when you assign `$flow.upload()` to it, you make it uploading immediately after file selection.

Second thing is to get $flow object in your controller. Two ways comes to my mind:

A. As instruction say, you have to use `flow-name` attribute:

```
<div flow-init flow-name="obj.flow">
```

Then you have reference to `$flow` in yours `$scope.obj.flow` property and you can use `$scope.obj.flow.upload()` method anywhere in your controller.

B. Put your "Upload" button inside flow directive block (as a descendant of element with `flow-init` attribute) and use `$flow` property of directive scope as a parameter in `ng-click`, for example:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="myUploadMedhot($flow)">Upload</button>
```

and inside `myUploadMethod(param)` just call `param.upload()`.